# Yarn global add doesn't work with aws codeartifact

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, aws-codeartifact

I configured aws codeArtifact to host my private npm packages. Everything works well, except when I try a to install something globally:

```
yarn global add serve
```

> yarn global v1.22.4 [1/4] Resolving packages...
> error An unexpected error occurred:
> "https://xxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/npm/my-repo/serve: Package, 'serve', not found.".info If you think this is a bug, please
> open a bug report with the information provided in
> "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\yarn-error.log".info
> Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about
> this command.

If I try the same command, without `global`, it works. How can I let codeArticact configured and still have `yarn global` working?